# How can I automatically restart gnome-shell coming out of suspend mode?

Tags: gnome, scripting, nvidia, gnome-shell

So, due to an issue with gnome-power-manager, gnome-shell, and my nvidia card, I'm left in the awkward position of coming out of suspension/sleep with my graphics broken. This problem resolves itself if I'm able to use the Alt + F2 command line to restart gnome-shell. However, sometimes, I'm unable to actually access that menu, and I have to do it blindly with the broken graphics.

Rather than switching to the power-eating nouveau drivers, I thought I'd just try to replicate the functionality of

```
r
```

or

```
restart
```

in the Alt + F2 menu in a script and have it execute upon recovering from suspend.

Any advice/ideas? I don't really know where to start.

(Alternately, if you've got another workaround/solution..?)

edit: these guys are discussing the same problem: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=932527

Answer (score 2):

**assuming this is a single-user system**, and assuming that a HUP signal is sufficient (causes gnome-shell to restart itself) You need to put a hook script containing something like

```
case "$1" in
  resume)
    killall -HUP gnome-shell
esac
```

into a `pm-utils` hook script, e.g `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99hup-gnome-shell`.

This will send a HUP signal to any `gnome-shell` instance running, and for a single user system there should only be one.

If HUP doesn't work, you could try TERM or KILL, and hope that your session manager starts up another one.

Comment: For some reason this works once, then resuming from suspend a second time kicks to login screen.